# Differentiating a product with an unknown function - sympy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I tried various searches but couldn't find a good google string to bring up the right results.

I have a product of the form

```
y = x*f(x)
```

where f is a function of x which is not known. I want sympy to differentiate y with respect to x. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Forget SymPy for a moment. How would you do it in general? I don't see how you can get a symbolic derivative for a functional form that is not know. How would you do this on pen and paper?

Comment: It's just the simple product rule, so you would get y'(x) = f(x) + xf'(x). So in this case, that is the answer I'd like it to return. It must be able to do it, I just don't know how.

Comment: How would you find f'(x) without knowing functional form? Do you want a numerical approximation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> x = sympy.Symbol("x")
>>> f = sympy.Function("f")
>>> y = x * f(x)
>>> y
x*f(x)
>>> y.diff(x)
x*Derivative(f(x), x) + f(x)
```