# How to obtain the derivative of sin and cos time dependent functions with respect to time in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

I'm trying to obtain the time derivative of *sin* and *cos* time dependent functions with sympy but I'm not getting the expected result.

When I derivate *cos(theta)* with respect to time I was expecting that I would obtain:

*-sin(theta)* * derivative of theta

and for the *sin* function:

*cos(theta)* * derivative of theta

but with this script

```
from sympy import Symbol, MatrixSymbol, Matrix, diff, cos, sin, Function

t = Symbol('t')

print(diff(cos(t), t))
```

when I derivate with respect to time I only get :

-sin(t)

and if I use:

```
print(diff(cos(theta), t))
```

I get

0.

Thank you in advance for any help.
Kind Regards
Ivo

Comment: If `theta` doesn't depend on `t` then the answer is correct isn't it? You are saying you want `theta` to depend on `t`?

Comment: My apologies that my question was not clear. That's the purpose. Theta to depend on t. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18554088/11946287 In summary you want to declare `theta = Function("theta")(t)`